# Block onClick events

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

Is it possible to block in some time frame (in the example 1s) `onClick` events after trigger?

0s: onClickEvent
200ms: Block the event
752ms: Block the event
1.2s: OnClickEvent
2.3s: OnClickEvent
2.6s: Block the event

How can I do without timers?

Comment: Whats your usecase?! Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: there are debounce libs out there:
https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Without timers? Seems like an arbitrary restriction.

Comment: "How can I do without timers?" — That's a very odd restriction for doing something that is time dependent. It is also very vague (what exactly do you mean by "timer"?) and stinks of being an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: store the time of the click, and test between the last time you processed the click, and current click time, ignore all inbetween

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const loadingTime = Date.now() + 1000;

 someEl.onclick = event => {
  if(Date.now() < loadingTime) event.stopPropagation();
};
```

Just prevent the event from propagating to other handlers.

Comment: Nice solution - the only limitation is lack of variable timings (tied in to 1 second); can be altered with an array of pre-defined timing intervals though.